# FPGA input capacitance

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, input-impedance

I want to estimate power consumption of a battery powered digital circuit that has a CPLD (Lattice LCMXO2-256HC). It receives 64 MHz signal into LVDS input and 10 MHz, 2.5V into a schmitt trigger input. Its output is ~50 kHz so I'm not concerned about the output capacitance. So the question is, how does the input capacitance depend on the input settings, supply voltage, packaging etc or its just the process variation? The datasheet specifies 3-9 pF at 1 MHz, 25°C but that's too broad for me, maybe I can narrow it down somehow?

[image]

Comment: "The datasheet specifies 3-9 pF at 1 MHz, 25°C **but that's too broad for me**" - why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott because the reactance of 3 pF is 829 ohm at 64 MHz and for 9 pF its 276. Quite a large difference when your overall consumption is around 10 mA.

Comment: Isn't your LVDS signal terminated with 100 ohms? That will dominate the power consumption whether the capacitive load is 829 or 276 ohms.

Comment: @ThePhoton no, the signal coming from a balun driven by an RF amplifier. And I decided to omit the termination because the traces are very short, around 1.5 mm. Or is it still a bad practice?

Comment: Depends on a lot of stuff you haven't shared.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm making a battery powered capacitive vibration sensor, it has a probe that modulates the frequency of an LC oscillator then the signal gets amplified and fed into the FPGA for demodulation. Ask if you need more info.

Comment: I opted for LVDS because it doesn't require as much amplification compared to conventional digital input, so I can use lower power amplifier instead of comparator

Comment: Datasheet of the amplifier, distance from amplifier to balun, and datasheet of the balun would be a start.

Comment: @ThePhoton it's just a basic class A amplifier like this one: imgur.com/a/Y3uaREV and the balun is ETC4-1-2TR. Distance is orders of millimeters too. My PCB doesn't have any traces longer than a few mm besides power supply trace. I'm getting 110 mVpp of differential voltage when probing the transformer with 15 pF oscilloscope probes.

Comment: I'm also thinking about trying another oscillator topology so I can omit the amplifier, maybe something like this https://imgur.com/a/6AZqmMD and connect the transformer to the collector of the right transistor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the capacitance comes from the packaging, and then from the gate/drain/source capacitance of the transistors. I don't think anyone but the manufacturer will be able to narrow the range for you. Someone on the internet may have anecdotal numbers to offer, but the manufacturer is free to change the package or the process at any time as long as the part still falls within the specified range. If you only need a few parts, measure the capacitance yourself.